# Decode Encrypted Password help me

Tags: .net, c, sql-server

Help me to decode belove password

68H++v5FX/kUty5/itzflw== Above is password store in sql table

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand algorithm I want decode it

Comment: Yes, and we're not a decoding service.

Answer (score 0):

The password is: `ebc1fefafe455ff914b72e7f8adcdf97`

The algorithm used is `password -> hexadecimal decode -> base64 encode`

To wit:

```
echo -n ebc1fefafe455ff914b72e7f8adcdf97 | xxd -p -r | base64
```

produces:

```
68H++v5FX/kUty5/itzflw==
```